# What is a Control Class in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am new to the GUI side of C# and I have been unit testing this C# Application.

I have been trying to use a class constructor which asks for a `Control` type object and a `bool`.

I have been trying to read about the `Control` class and I could not understand what it is.

I would highly appreciate it if somebody could explain to me in simple terms what `Control` class is and what it's relation to Forms.

Comment: here you go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What would you need a control class for ?

Comment: @AngeloCharl - you might not need the control class directly, but rather an object (still a control type) that extends from it.

Comment: All winform control types (even `Form`) inherits from `Control` at some level, so any method that has a `Control` parameter can accept any type of UI control.  At that point it's just basic polymorphism.

Comment: @AngeloCharl Controls are user interface elements, like buttons, text boxes, etc. etc. In winforms, the `Control` class is a "base class" for all of them. "What's a base class?!" you ask! That'll take some reading about the concept of "inheritance" in languages like C#; [here's an article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx).

Comment: If you're struggling with the concept of what a "class" is, [start with this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx).

Comment: Ah. I see! thanks! That is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Windows forms is build upon a object hierarchy. All the UI controls that use a ControlTemplate to define their appearance is inherited from Control class. In OO this type of parent class inheritance is called as base class.

if you look at the Object Hierarchy it looks as follows

```
- System.Windows.Forms.Control
     -System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl
       -System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl
          -System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

So Form is a Control. Whatever Control can do Form can do it too because its inherited. Hope it clears out your question.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

Defines the base class for controls, which are components with visual representation.

Basically it is the base class for all visual components. TextBox, DropDown etc... 
It has basic functions and methods to define Visibility, Size etc.

Comment: it could be better if you could just give the link in comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is actually a while back, to make things simple for you think of a Control Class as a class that contains all visual elements for your GUI. If you need a scroll bar all you do is inherit from that class by instantiating an object which you use to create the graphical representation of your scroll bar. Now, that graphical representation(scrollbar or button ...) provides the UI for you to implement(control) your business logic on how you will interact with data.